# Configuring Spring Kafka for two separate clusters

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Is it possible to configure Kafka for working with two separate clusters in single spring boot application?

**Use case:** I have two clusters with replicas + zookeeper:

- Cluster #1 *bootstrap-servers*: `server1.example.com,server2.example.com,server3.example.com`
- Cluster #2 *bootstrap-servers*: `target-server1.example.com,target-server2.example.com,target-server3.example.com`

I need to consume the message from `Cluster #1` then do some calculations based on that data and produce the results to `Cluster #2` topic. Is there any way to configure Kafka in single Spring application to handle this approach?

Comment: yes you can, have you tried anything ? can you show the code ?

Comment: The alternative is to just use one cluster, then use Kafka Connect or MirrorMaker to send data to the other... Kafka Streams only works with one cluster

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but if you want to consume and produce with both, you have to manually configure the consumer and producer factory `@Bean`s etc.

Boot can only auto configure one of each from properties.

But if you are simply consuming from one cluster and producing to another, it **can** be done with properties.

Use

```
spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=...
...
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=...
```

these will override the common properties.

Comment: hmm I'm trying to do this locally, I have 2 kafka docker containers running, but the produced message still end up on the consumer container.. weird thing is that when I produce the first message the topic is created on the producer kafka as well.

Comment: Ask a new question showing code, configuration and logs.